# sys.getrefcount return non continuous value for different scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how the memory allocated in python.For that,I used to playing on python.But I got stuck on below issue.

For the below code, If I use 10 instead of 1000 I got expected reference count value within the function

```
import sys
def show_ref_count(a):
    print("ref count of 1000 within function : ",sys.getrefcount(1000))
    print("adrs of a : ",id(a))

# main function
a = 1000
b = 1000
c = 1000
print("ref count of 1000 : ",sys.getrefcount(1000))
print("adrs of a : ",id(a))
show_ref_count(a)
```

And the output for the code is

```
ref count of 1000 :  6
adrs of a :  140309334530448
ref count of 1000 within function :  3
adrs of a :  140309334530448
```

**Integer 1000 stored in Memory loc : 140309334530448 and same address used by both main and show_ref_count**. But in show_ref_count function, reference count for 1000 is showing as 3 not 7.Why?

Comment: You are calling `sys.getrefcount(1000)` instead of `sys.getrefcount(a)` in the function. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes.Because for Integer value 10 I got reference count 8.But for 1000 I got 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `1000` initialized inside `main` and `1000` inside `show_ref_count` are not the same objects. You can add one line to your function

```
import sys
def show_ref_count(a):
    print("ref count of 1000 within a function: ", sys.getrefcount(1000))
    print("addr of var: ", id(a))
    print("addr of 1000 within function: ", id(1000))

# main function
a = 1000
b = 1000
c = 1000

print("ref count of 1000: ", sys.getrefcount(1000))
print("addr of a: ", id(a))
print("addr of 1000: ", id(1000))

show_ref_count(a)
```

and check the output

```
ref count of 1000:  3
addr of a:  140646358917616
addr of 1000:  140646358918000

ref count of 1000 within a function:  2
addr of var:  140646358917616
addr of 1000 within function:  140646390098512
```

to figure out that these two `1000`'s are actually different objects, so the number of refs is also different.

Note: also `a` being initialized with `1000` is not the same object, and also has a different address (if you take a look on the output above). [It happens since variables in Python are not actually variables but rather 'names' of objects.](https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/#understanding-variables) From the article an overall process looks as follows:

> 1. Create a PyObject
> 2. Set the typecode to integer for the PyObject
> 3. Set the value to `1000` for the PyObject
> 4. Create a name called `a`
> 5. Point `a` to the new PyObject
> 6. Increase the refcount of the PyObject by `1`